# How to get the value of prop (which could be multi-line) in JSX tag using regex?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, jsx, regex-group

I want to get the value of title props from these JSX elements,

```
      <Story title={'Disabled Text Input'}>
        <TextInput label="Disabled Text Input" disabled />
      </Story>
      <Story 
         title={'Disabled ways for
                 Text Input to work'}>
        <TextInput label="Disabled Text Input" 
          disabled 
          {...someExtraProps}/>
      </Story>
```

For the above example,

*Disabled Text Input*

*Disabled ways for Text Input to work*

I am trying to use regex, using grouping,

> I was able to get the children of Story JSX element, using
> `/<Story[^]+?>(?<component>[^$]*?)<\/Story>/g`

but struggling with getting value of the title prop.
As it could be in any of the below forms,

```
title={"some"}
title="Some"
title='Some'
title={'Some'}
```

Comment: You can't reliably do that with a single regular expression. JSX, like HTML, is too complex for that. If you want to parse JSX, you need a JSX parser, not a regular expression.

Comment: I do not actually want to use it for rendering purposes. But a simple extraction. I get we can use parsers, AST extractors all that. But just looking for regex.

Comment: I'm not talking about rendering. I mean to extract data reliably from JSX, you need a parser, not a regular expression.

Comment: Yup, you are right. To extract JSX data, a parser is the most reliable way. The usecase I am targeting is writing it to a markdown along with the children of <Story/>. So not sure which jsx-parser would help me extract it efficiently. If you have any parser in mind, do let me know. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did use regex as my first step to the solution.
But then I came across this toolbox,
[React-Docgen](https://github.com/reactjs/react-docgen) which served the exact purpose of extracting information for document generation.